# Сохранение положения выбранного option в разных select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Как сохранить выбранное положение option в select с нужным классом. В js и jQ не силён. Буду благодарен за помощь.

UPD: попробую перефразировать вопрос. Если у select c определенным классом выбран, например, option:nth-child(2), то у всех селектов, с этим же классом, нужно выбрать этот же option, даже при перезагрузке страницы. Надеюсь объяснил

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "сохранить выбранное положение"?

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что когда пользователь выбирает определенный пункт в селекте, его nth-child сохранялся и выбирался по умолчанию у всех селектов с определенным классом

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понял, настолько и сделал. Смотреть -> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cngf47ev/1/)

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
 let selClass = $(this).attr('class'),
    optVal = $(this).val();
  $('.'+selClass).val(optVal);
 checkSelect($(this),optVal,selClass);
});

function checkSelect(elem,elemValue,elemClass) {
 let el = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('select'));
  let obj = {class:elemClass,value:elemValue};
 if (elemValue != '-1' && el != null) { 
    let id = null;
    $(el).each(function(key,elem){
      if (elem.class == elemClass) {
       id = key;
      }
    });
    if (id!=null) {
     el[id] = obj;
    } else {
     el.push(obj);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('select', JSON.stringify(el));
  } else {
   localStorage.setItem('select', JSON.stringify([obj]));
  }
}

$(function(){
 let elems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('select'));
  if (elems!=null) {
    $(elems).each(function(key,elem){
     $('.'+elem.class).val(elem.value);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="s1">
  <option value="-1" selected hidden>choose value</option>
  <option value="s1">s1</option>
  <option value="s2">s2</option>
  <option value="s3">s3</option>
</select>
<select class="s1">
  <option value="-1" selected hidden>choose value</option>
  <option value="s1">s1</option>
  <option value="s2">s2</option>
  <option value="s3">s3</option>
</select>
<select class="s2">
  <option value="-1" selected hidden>choose value</option>
  <option value="s1">s1</option>
  <option value="s2">s2</option>
  <option value="s3">s3</option>
</select>
<select class="s2">
  <option value="-1" selected hidden>choose value</option>
  <option value="s1">s1</option>
  <option value="s2">s2</option>
  <option value="s3">s3</option>
</select>
<select class="s3">
  <option value="-1" selected hidden>choose value</option>
  <option value="s1">s1</option>
  <option value="s2">s2</option>
  <option value="s3">s3</option>
</select>
<select class="s3">
  <option value="-1" selected hidden>choose value</option>
  <option value="s1">s1</option>
  <option value="s2">s2</option>
  <option value="s3">s3</option>
</select>
```

*З.Ы. если использовать для хранения localStorage, то надо делать удаление добавленного эл-та, к примеру, во время/после logout'а*

Comment: А как быть, если, например, <select class="s3"> появляется позже, при выборе определенного <option> в <select class="s1">. Я к тому, что ваш вариант работает, при условии что все селекты видны на странице, а что делать если они подгружаются при определенных условиях. Вытащить сюда код формы возможности нет

Comment: @Evgen Всё зависит от того, как появляется select. Если он просто скрывается то всё и так должно работать, но если же он добавляется как новый эл-т на страницу то надо добавить обработку ещё. Но, опять таки, не совсем вас понял. Опишите конкретней ситуацию, пошагово, если можно.

Comment: Ситуация такая: есть 5 селектов, последний, т.е 5ый, подгружается в зависимости от того, что выбрано в первых четырех. select5 это разные селекты со своими id, но option у них одинаковые, и есть общий class. Вот я и думаю, как сохранить выбранное пользователем положение в select5, либо фиксировать по value и выбирать его при смене id select5

Answer (score -1):

Подставьте свои значения:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select .your-class').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Само собой что jq должен быть подключен.